# Trying to print a simple string: [Warning] conflicting types for 'rawrprint' [enabled by default]

Tags: c

When I try to run the following program, it prints out the string but I still receive a warning:
**18    6   C:\Users\Starhowl\Documents\C problems\consoleproj\main.c   [Warning] conflicting types for 'rawrprint' [enabled by default]**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *text = "my test";
char *texta[] = {"array test", "mwrawr"};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

rawrprint(texta);

return 0;
}

void rawrprint(char *hurr){
    printf("%s", hurr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `texta` is an array of pointer to `char`, and your `rawrprint()` requires its arguments has type of pointer to `char`. You should call it using `texta[0]` or `texta[1]` as its argument, like this:

```
rawrprint(texta[0]);
```

Additionally, you had better declare a function before you call it, so that compiler can check the types of argument(s) and return value, and issue warnings if you call it improperly.

Comment: OP also has a forward reference, so the compiler will assume that `rawrprint` returns `int`, which it doesn't.

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, that is another problem of that code. Thank you for point that out.

Comment: Passing texta[0] or texta[1] gives me the same compiler warning? How can I declare the function before I call it?

Comment: @Starhowl Put `void rawrprint(char *);` before `main()`.